# lsmeans package - Kenward-Roger df adjusment for F-tests

Tags: r

I have looked into the `lsmeans` package in R. The package description states than if the `pbkrtest` package is installed, then for `lme4` objects the degrees of freedom for F-tests are adjusted according to Kenward and Roger.
However, with the `pbkrtest` package installed and loaded, the degrees of freedom are still the default ones (asymptotic):

Example:

```
require(lsmeans)
require(nlme)
require(pbkrtest)

Oats.lme <- lme(yield ~ factor(nitro) + Variety, random = ~1 | Block/Variety,
    subset = -c(1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55), data = Oats)
lsmeans(Oats.lme, list(poly ~ nitro, pairwise ~ Variety))
```

Output:

```
$`lsmeans of nitro`
 nitro    lsmean       SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
   0.0  78.89205 7.280578 NA  64.62065  93.16344
   0.2  97.03422 7.128674 NA  83.06058 111.00785
   0.4 114.19813 7.128853 NA 100.22415 128.17212
   0.6 124.06857 7.067271 NA 110.21529 137.92184
```

...

P values are asymptotic

...

I am using R version 3.02 and the packages are freshly installed.

```
packageVersion("lsmeans")
[1] '2.0.4'
```

Comment: As a suggestion, I wonder if you might have some more luck getting answers here on Cross validated? Have you had a look at this resource which talks about changes to the degree of freedom calculations within lsmeans()? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/lsmeans-changes.pdf

Comment: The functions from `pbkrtest`, at least, only work with fits from the newer `lme4` package (i.e. using `lmer()`), not from the `nlme` package (using `lme()`).

Answer (score 4):

`?lsmeans` states (emphasis added)

> **For models fitted using the ‘lme4’ package**, degrees of freedom are obtained using the Kenward-Roger (1997) method as implemented in the package ‘pbkrtest’, if it is installed. If ‘pbkrtest’ is not installed, the degrees of freedom are set to ‘NA’ and asymptotic results are displayed.

That means you have to use `lme4::lmer`, not `nlme::lme`, to fit your model.

```
require(lsmeans)
require(lme4)
require(pbkrtest)

Oats.lmer <- lmer(yield ~ factor(nitro) + Variety+
            (1 | Block/Variety),
     subset = -c(1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55), data = Oats)
lsmeans(Oats.lmer, list(poly ~ nitro, pairwise ~ Variety))
```

The results do have adjusted df:

```
## $`lsmeans of nitro`
##  nitro    lsmean       SE   df  lower.CL  upper.CL
##    0.0  78.89207 7.294379 7.78  61.98930  95.79484
##    0.2  97.03425 7.136271 7.19  80.25029 113.81822
##    0.4 114.19816 7.136186 7.19  97.41454 130.98179
##    0.6 124.06857 7.070235 6.95 107.32795 140.80919
```

Comment: Hello. I don't see where you use `pbkrtest`  in this code. It is automatically "detected" by `lsmeans` ?